# To pass a php value in an array in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a function like bellow

```
if(!function_exists('generate_share_urls')) {
  function generate_share_urls() {
      $title = the_title();
      $content = the_content();
    $share_urls = array (
      'facebook'      => 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=',
      'twitter'       => 'http://twitter.com/share?url=',
      'google_plus'   => 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=',
      'linkedin'      => 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=',
      'pinterest'     => 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=',
      'email'         => 'mailto:?subject={'.$title.'}&body='.$content.',
      'permalink'     => ''
   );
   return $share_urls;
  }
}
```

Now when run the function i cant find the $title and the $content of the page. Is there any fault with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title()` and `the_content()` will **print** the title/content, not return it. What you need instead are the `get_` functions:

```
if(!function_exists('generate_share_urls')) {
  function generate_share_urls() {
      $title = get_the_title();
      $content = get_the_content();
    $share_urls = array (
      'facebook'      => 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=',
      'twitter'       => 'http://twitter.com/share?url=',
      'google_plus'   => 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=',
      'linkedin'      => 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=',
      'pinterest'     => 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=',
      'email'         => 'mailto:?subject={'.$title.'}&body='.$content.',
      'permalink'     => ''
   );
   return $share_urls;
  }
}
```

Comment: from the syntax highlighting, he may have an unclosed quote in there as well, not sure if he just copied it wrong or whether it's really an error...

Comment: Thank you. I have found what i want.